# Static pthreads mutex initialization

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, static-initialization

Using pthreads, how would one, in C, initialize a static array of mutexes?

For a single static mutex, it seems I can use PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER. But what about an static array of them? As, in for example,

```
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

/*initialize static mutex array*/
static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_THREADS] = ...?
```

Or must they be allocated dynamically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a C99 conforming compiler you can use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__basic__list__operations.html) to do your initialization:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_THREADS] =
  { P99_DUPL(NUM_THREADS, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER) };
```

This just repeats the token sequence `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,` the requested number of times.

For this to work you only have to be sure that `NUM_THREADS` doesn't expand to a variable but to a decimal integer constant that is visible to the preprocessor and that is not too large.

Answer (score 25):

No, you don't have to create them dynamically. You can use a static array, you just have to get them all set up before you use them. You can do:

```
#define NUM_THREADS 5
static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_THREADS] = {
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
};
```

which is prone to errors if you ever change `NUM_THREADS`, though that can be fixed with something like:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[] = {
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
};
#define NUM_THREADS (sizeof(mutexes)/sizeof(*mutexes))
```

Alternatively, you can do it with code, such as:

```
#define NUM_THREADS 5
static pthread_mutex_t mutexes[NUM_THREADS];

// Other stuff

int main (void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutexes[i], NULL);
    // Now you can use them safely.

    return 0;
}
```

In all those cases, they're correctly set up before you try to use them. In fact, I'd do it well before you do *any* threading stuff but that's just me being paranoid.

Comment: In the first sample the use of `NUM_THREADS` is not necessary.  It may help you to catch certain errors, but also to commit certain other ones.

Comment: you could also use BOOST_PP_ENUM since it only requires c99 preprocessor