# (pthread) How to make dynamic array mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Using pthreads, how would one, in C, initialize array of mutexes?

For a single mutex, it seems I can use PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER. But what about an array of them? As, in for example,

```
#include <pthread.h>

/*initialize mutex array*/
pthread_mutex_t mutexes[] = ...?
```

is there a way to make the mutex array dynamic?

And what is the difference between static and non-static mutexes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static pthreads mutex initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138778/static-pthreads-mutex-initialization)

Comment: I need dynamic array.

Comment: Using `pthread_mutex_init`?